# dlopen core dumped when play sound

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I got a core dump on embeded linux platform when playing sound.
I used QT for GUI, the callstack is:

```
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x411740e4 in dlopen () from /lib/libdl.so.0
(gdb) bt
#0  0x411740e4 in dlopen () from /lib/libdl.so.0
#1  0x40194a04 in snd_dlopen () from /nand/usr/lib/libasound.so.2
#2  0x40190cc8 in ?? () from /nand/usr/lib/libasound.so.2
(gdb) thread apply all bt

Thread 7 (process 511):
#0  0x405e15c8 in ?? () from /nand/usr/lib/libQtGui.so.4
Cannot access memory at address 0x2

Thread 6 (process 538):
#0  0x410dda1c in read () from /lib/libc.so.0
#1  0x40fdbe14 in read () from /lib/libpthread.so.0
#2  0x4014b924 in SysUtil_GetALSEventValue () at ALSPSensor.cpp:46
#3  0x00040af0 in ALSensor::operateBackLight (this=<value optimized out>) at    src/PALSSensorHandle.cpp:97
#4  0x00040c04 in ALSensor::run (this=0x12a218) at src/PALSSensorHandle.cpp:76
#5  0x40d4d4f8 in ?? () from /nand/usr/lib/libQtCore.so.4
Thread 5 (process 537):
#0  0x410dda1c in read () from /lib/libc.so.0
#1  0x40fdbe14 in read () from /lib/libpthread.so.0
#2  0x4014b5fc in SysUtil_GetPSEventValue () at ALSPSensor.cpp:163
#3  0x00040c54 in PSensor::operateBackLight (this=<value optimized out>) at src/PALSSensorHandle.cpp:83
#4  0x00040d20 in PSensor::run (this=0x11ecf8) at src/PALSSensorHandle.cpp:66
#5  0x40d4d4f8 in ?? () from /nand/usr/lib/libQtCore.so.4

Thread 4 (process 536):
#0  0x4117e730 in mq_receive () from /lib/librt.so.0
#1  0x40219fa4 in BidirctMsgQueue::get (this=0x130ba8, msg_len=0xbe5ffd3c) at BidirctMsgQueue.cpp:56
#2  0x0003fb0c in MqReceiver::run (this=0x12b270) at src/MqReceiver.cpp:45
#3  0x40d4d4f8 in ?? () from /nand/usr/lib/libQtCore.so.4

Thread 3 (process 535):
#0  0x410ddfd8 in select () from /lib/libc.so.0
#1  0x4009897c in ipc_block_recv (sock=27, recv_message=0xbe7ffc90) at ipc.cpp:123
#2  0x40022c74 in CSipMsgControl::InitSipMsg (this=0x145ea8) at sipmsgcontrol.cpp:170
#3  0x40022cb8 in CSipMsgControl::run (this=0xfffffdfe) at sipmsgcontrol.cpp:119
#4  0x40d4d4f8 in ?? () from /nand/usr/lib/libQtCore.so.4
Thread 2 (process 534):
#0  0x410dd5ac in poll () from /lib/libc.so.0
#1  0x40fd87d4 in __pthread_manager () from /lib/libpthread.so.0
Backtrace stopped: frame did not save the PC
Thread 1 (process 1416):
#0  0x411740e4 in dlopen () from /lib/libdl.so.0
#1  0x40194a04 in snd_dlopen () from /nand/usr/lib/libasound.so.2
#2  0x40190cc8 in ?? () from /nand/usr/lib/libasound.so.2
(gdb)
```

Comment: It doesn't have to be that thread which causes the crash, it could be any thread. You have to check all your code mentioned in all stack-traces to make sure you don't use any uninitialized, stray or `NULL` pointers.

Comment: This issue is hard to reproduce, I checked all the code in stack-traces, and found nothing. do you have more tips.

Comment: Memory-checking tools such as [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) might help, as will turning on more warnings when building and fixing them.